# PHP multi IF condition with user block feature

Tags: php

I want create a login script with php where I added various condition but it goes to wrong when I run it.

I want make "Email Verification" - as primary then "LogCount" then "Status" and then all is ="1" then show **dashboard.php**

```
<?php
$msg = "";

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    include("config.php");
    //$con = new mysqli('localhost', 'research_emailC', 'test123', 'research_phpEmailConfirmation');

    $username = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $password = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

    if ($username == "" || $password == "")
        $msg = "Please check your inputs!";
    else {
        $sql = $con->query("SELECT ID, password, isEmailConfirmed, Status FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
        if ($sql->num_rows > 0) {
            $data = $sql->fetch_array();
            //if (password_verify($password, $data['password'])) {
                if ($data['isEmailConfirmed'] == 0)
                    $msg = "Please verify your email!";
                else {
                    $msg = "You have been logged in";
                }
            }else
                $msg = "Please check your identity";
        }

        if ($data['Status'] == 0)
            $msg = "Your account is suspended!";
        else{
            $msg = "Something went wrong!";
        } 

        if ($data['LogCount'] == 0)
            msg=" you are new user ";
        else{
            $msg = "Something wrong here!";
        } 

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Escaping a hashed password will changed the value thus will it's be better to cut that out and use prepared statements.

Comment: Don't just check for `== ""` what if I added a space? Use `trim` and `empty`.

Comment: and one more thing you have one extraa `}` at the end

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<?php
$msg = "";

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    include("config.php");
    //$con = new mysqli('localhost', 'research_emailC', 'test123', 'research_phpEmailConfirmation');

    $username = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $password = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

    $suc = 1;


    if ($username == "" || $password == "")
        $msg = "Please check your inputs!";
        $suc = 0;
    else{
        $sql = $con->query("SELECT ID, password, isEmailConfirmed, Status FROM users WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'");
        //LogCount field is not taken here

        if ($sql->num_rows > 0) {
            $data = $sql->fetch_array();
            if ($data['isEmailConfirmed'] == 0){
                $msg = "Please verify your email!";
                $suc = 0;
            }
            if ($data['Status'] == 0){
                $msg = "Your account is suspended!";
                $suc = 0;
            }
        }else{
            $msg = "Please check your username/password";
            $suc = 0;
        }
    }

    if ($suc == 1){
        //if take the LogCount field please check the following
        if ($data['LogCount'] == 0){
            msg = " you are new user ";//Welcome to our site
        }else{
            //Increase the LogCount Here
            msg = " You have been logged in";
        }               
        //Otherwise
        msg = " You have been logged in";
        //Set session value 
        //Re-direct to dashboard Page
    }else{
        //Same Login Page
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Only says `Please check your username/password` even in my database I modified `Status, isEmailConfirmed, LogCount` column as zero..

Comment: actually I wish to create like this script as my knowledge I made it but error comes at `else` condition. Could you have a look at this issue and share a pastebin. https://pastebin.com/qb7XCKzT

Comment: Not working without any submitting redirect based on last command. This is my full HTML, PHP script why you not run it in localhost or check...PLS REVIEW...https://pastebin.com/QP5G520K

Comment: AWAITING FOR RESPOND

Comment: @JohnMarks Sorry I have some other work.. I will answer, If i know or my free time only.. And also I am not working php currently my pc also dont have php. So I cant check

Comment: Ok, but if tour don't Know you must not respond wrong script. Possible from your could you pass this post to senior or tag somebody who might give this answer..